# Не создаётся own dbus в сервисе

Tags: linux, c

Если запустить обычным способом из консоли, то программа регистрируется на dbus шине и всё нормально работает, но если эту программу запустить через systemctl, то dbus сначала создается, а потом отключается. вот часть кода.

```
/* Introspection data for the service we are exporting */
static const gchar introspection_xml[] =
  "<node>"
  "  <interface name='com.xverizex.trade_bot.status'>"
  "    <method name='stop_trading'>"
  "      <arg type='u' name='status' direction='out'/>"
  "    </method>"
  "    <method name='start_trading'>"
  "      <arg type='u' name='status' direction='out'/>"
  "    </method>"
  "  <property type='u' name='is_connected' access='read'/>"
  "  <signal name='connection_changed'>"
  "    <arg type='u' name='status'/>"
  "  </signal>"
  "  </interface>"
  "</node>";
...
static void
on_name_acquired (GDBusConnection *connection,
                  const gchar     *name,
                  gpointer         user_data)
{
}

static void
on_name_lost (GDBusConnection *connection,
              const gchar     *name,
              gpointer         user_data)
{
}

static void set_server_dbus ( void ) {
    unsigned int owner_id;
    introspection_data = g_dbus_node_info_new_for_xml (introspection_xml, NULL);

    owner_id = g_bus_own_name ( G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
            "com.xverizex.trade_bot",
            G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_ALLOW_REPLACEMENT | G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_REPLACE,
            on_bus_acquired,
            on_name_acquired,
            on_name_lost,
            NULL,
            NULL );
    printf ( "owner_id: %d\n", owner_id );
}
...
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    init_buffers ( );
    mysql = mysql_init ( NULL );
    if ( mysql_real_connect ( mysql, "localhost", "gag", "gag", "binance", 0, NULL, 0 ) == NULL ) {
        printf ( "не правильные данные для базы данных.\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    set_server_dbus ( );
    subscribe_to_net_device ( );

    if ( power_net == 100 ) {
        connect_to_network ( );
        printf ( "!ok\n" );
    }

    GMainLoop *loop;
    loop = g_main_loop_new ( NULL, FALSE );
    g_main_loop_run ( loop );
    return 0;
}
```

после запуска в сервисе, вызывается функция on_name_lost. Вот service файл trade_bot.service

```
[Unit]
Description = trade bot
After = multi-user.target dbus.service
Requires = dbus.service

[Service]
Type = idle
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/trade_bot

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

вот makefile

```
LIBS=`pkg-config --libs gio-unix-2.0,libcurl,glib-2.0,libssl,json-c,mysqlclient --cflags gio-unix-2.0,libcurl,glib-2.0,libssl,json-c,mysqlclient`
all:
    gcc src/main.c src/log.c src/websocket_client.c $(LIBS) -pthread -o trade_bot
install:
    install trade_bot /usr/local/bin
    cp com.xverizex.trade_bot.desktop /usr/share/applications
    cp com.xverizex.trade_bot.conf /etc/dbus-1/session.d/
    cp com.xverizex.trade_bot.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services
install_service:
    cp trade_bot.service /etc/systemd/system
    cp trade_bot.service /lib/systemd/system
    systemctl enable trade_bot.service
clean:
    rm trade_bot
```

вот com.xverizex.trade_bot.conf

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="com.xverizex.trade_bot"/>
                <allow send_destination="com.xverizex.trade_bot"/>
        </policy>
        <policy user="cf">
                <allow own="com.xverizex.trade_bot"/>
                <allow send_destination="com.xverizex.trade_bot"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

вот com.xverizex.trade_bot.service

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=com.xverizex.trade_bot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/trade_bot
User=cf
```

Comment: из того за что зацепился глаз — поидей через systemd имеет смысл запускать только то, что слушает на системной шине, а не на сесионной... а для сессионной dbus поидей сам должен стартовать твоё приложение при запросе, но только для `cf` и `root`'а...

Comment: @Fat-Zer так, а как сделать, чтобы запускался сервис с own dbus? Или как то можно по другому сделать это, чтобы был доступен у приложения интерфейс через dbus? Если делать через g_application_new, то работает, но я не понимаю как создать интерфейс. а через own понятно, но сервис не даёт шине dbus работать.

Comment: Что именно ты подразумеваешь под «dbus own»? Единственное, в чём я вижу явную ошибку в вопросе — ты пытаешься запустить с помощью `systemd` приложение, которое слушает сессионную шину (`G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION`), но systemd запускает демоны, которые ,вообще говоря, не должны быть привязаны ни к какой сессии пользователя… короче говоря, это довольно бессмысленное действие… нужно или работать на системной шине, если нужно запускать один экземпляр приложения на систему, или вообще не трогать systemd и запускать его только средствами dbus'а, или как-то ещё изощрятся...

Comment: дисклеймер: я не так хорошо знаю/понимаю устройство dbus'а вообще, стека технологий freedesktop.org завязанных на нём и GDBus в частности...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я как бы использую systemctl - это же вроде тоже systemd? через systemctl запускаю службы. но вот посмотри что такое own - g_bus_own_name. можешь в документации в программе devhelp посмотреть. она срабатывает в сторону отключения на шине. а мне надо чтобы она не отключалась. если я обычное приложение сделаю на шине с помощью g_application, то всё нормально работает, но нельзя сделать интерфейс.

Comment: не распарсил последнее сообщение... прямой вопрос: почему ты подключаешься на сессионную шину? это сознательное решение? ты понимаешь разницу между сессионной и системной шиной? зачем ты приложение запускаемое через systemd пытаешься подключить на сессионную шину? или зачем ты пытаешься запустить приложение, которое подключается на сессионную шину, через systemd?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я решил попробовать несколько вариантов, когда не получилось с помощью сервиса подключиться к сессионной шине. тогда и попробовал systemd в плане создания файлов конфига, думал что это поможет. мне нужно правильное решение. может исходники какой нибудь программы посмотреть?

Comment: ладно... я всё равно не понимаю, какого именно поведения ты хочешь добиться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я хочу, чтобы программа в сервисе была зарегистрирована на шине и ей можно было управлять через другое приложение. В данном случае после регистрации, шина пропадает сразу, а если запустить не через сервис, а обычным способом, то шина не пропадает.

Comment: Экземпляр программы должен запускаться один на систему или один на сессию пользователя? Программа должна запускаться при первом обращении к ней по dbus'у или при загрузке/логине? Она должна запускаться от имени конкретного пользователя или любого? Для конкретного пользователя или для любого? Что ты подразумеваешь под следующими словосочетаниями: «*программа в сервисе*», «*шина пропадает*», «*запустить через сервис*», «*запустить … обычным способом*»? ну и плюс на предыдущую серию вопросов ты так и не ответил…

Comment: @Fat-Zer сейчас попробую объяснить. запуск через сервис - это запуск с помощью systemctl start trade_bot. Через сервис работает программа, если я не использую own, а использую простой функционал с помощью g_application_new. Если я запускаю own от своего пользователя, не через systemctl, то его имя на шине dbus можно посмотреть с помощью программы qdbusviewer, называется com.xverizex.trade_bot. Если я запущу через systemctl, то own не создает на шине dbus com.xverizex.trade_bot, а просто откразывается создавать.

Comment: так... что-то проясняется... определённости ради, что такое «простой функционал с помощью g_application_new»? при запуске через `systemctl` невозможно соединиться с сесионной шиной т.к. в таком случае запуск происходит независимо от какой-либо сессии (о чём я и говорю с самого начала) `g_bus_own_name` соответственно проваливается и сообщает об этом вызовом `on_name_lost()`... т.е. надо или использовать другие способы запуска, или использовать системную шину.

Comment: @Fat-Zer простой функционал с помощью g_application_new, я точно не проверял, но это как бы работает, я не смотрел, появляется ли на шине dbus название этой программы, потому что работала без ошибок. хотя может тоже не появляется на шине dbus. но я видел что pulseaudio работает на сессионной шине, хотя я что-то не нашел её файл как сервис. а как тогда в системную шину сделать, чтобы работала?

Comment: просто замени `G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION` на `G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM`… +сделать то же самое в клиенте… + ещё, скорей всего, нужно создать файл с разрешениями в `/etc/dbus-1/system.d` по аналогии с уже имеющимися… и не забудь перезагрузить настройки dbus'а… а для пульсы dbus — не основной интерфейс, так что с ним она слабо связана и может запускаться по-разному: её может спавнить первый процесс, который попытается к ней подключится и обнаружит, что демона нет, она может запускаться из `/etc/xdg/autostart`, а может с помощью пользовательских модулей `systemd` (см. ключ `--user`), сразу или через сокет…

Comment: @Fat-Zer хорошо, спасибо.